# InboxSDK "Error creating AppId: Invalid app id seed"

Tags: inboxsdk

Trying to register an app for InboxSDK here: https://www.inboxsdk.com/register

Every AppID I try and register results in the error:

""Error creating AppId:
Invalid app id seed"

I have tried using random strings, random numbers, the Chrome Extension ID, and every time I get that error. Is there a certain syntax or ID source  I need to use that I'm missing?

Tried the 32char Chrome extension ID, strings of numbers, letters and combinations.

Looked on stackoverflow and google search and I can't see any docs on required formats, or others having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

> The AppId needs to be an alpha numeric string with no spaces or punctuation

From InboxSDK's GitHub discussions here https://github.com/InboxSDK/InboxSDK/discussions/944#discussioncomment-6430212.